# How can I disable the addons-bar in firefox on startup

Tags: firefox, user-interface

Recent Firefox (2 years+) features a so called *addons bar* which is usually used to house icons of user installed extensions. I would like some assistance disabling (hiding) that bar on startup.

The preferred way would be through the application settings (about:config). Alternatively I have vimperator, which can probably be told to execute a macro on startup (Ctrl-/) to close that bar.

The bar I'm talking about:

[image: addons bar]

Comment: Which OS is that? In Windows and Ubuntu, One can just right-click on the add-on bar and uncheck the 'Add-on Bar' option.

Comment: You could also click on the "X". Firefox should remember that you have hidden the bar and on the next start-up, it won't be displayed.